# FORTRAN DLL calling convention from MapleSim / Modelica

Tags: dll, fortran, calling-convention, modelica

Modelica modeling language supports calling functions from external FORTRAN DLLs, however, MapleSim only includes the support of calling functions from C DLLs even though it says it has full support for the Modelica language, and I have no choice but to use this FORTRAN DLL (I can't reprogram it in C nor I can use other Modelica evironments than MapleSim), so I'm not in the undocumented features realm.

I tried forcing MapleSim to include the FORTRAN DLL and created a custom component but its not working. This is the code I got when I opened the custom component: [relevant portion only]

```
    model ExternalCode

    function GETPSAT
        input Real TC;
        output Real PC;
    external "C" PC = GETPSAT(TC)
        annotation (
            Library = "C:/Path/To/My/DLL/FORTRAN.dll", __Maplesoft_callconv = "stdcall");
    end GETPSAT;

    equation
        (PC) = GETPSAT(TC);
        annotation (
            experiment(__Maplesoft_engine = 2));
    end ExternalCode;
```

I know I should change `external "C"` to `external "FORTRAN"`, but what should I should I do with `__Maplesoft_callconv = "stdcall"`? ie: what is the call convention for FORTRAN functions? (I know nothing on the subject of calling conventions).

Note the parent evnironment of MapleSim 6.1 (Maple 17) supports importing external functions from FORTRAN so I think there is a possibility MapleSim will support it despite it being undocumented.

edit: By the way, the DLL was compiled with Compaq visual fortran (I don't remember the version)

edit2: The function in the FORTRAN DLL is exported as follows:

```
FUNCTION GETPSAT(TC) 
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'GETPSAT' :: GETPSAT
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: GETPSAT
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: TC
GETPSAT=PSAT11(TC)
RETURN
END
```

edit3: I don't know it this helps, but the same function can be called from C# like this:

```
    [DllImport("C:\\Path\\To\\My\\DLL\\FORTRAN.dll")]
    static extern float GETPSAT(float T);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular Fortran function should behave like a completely normal C function because of the attributes it has. Do not add any `external(FORTRAN)` or similar. Its name should be `GETPSAT` and it accepts 1 float `TC` by value.

Use the same `"stdcal"` attribute, it is default for the DEC, Compaq and Intel Fortran https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mkl_userguide_win/GUID-E74229B0-7389-46A6-9FCF-91CD6CD5B0E4.htm

Comment: Yes. `external "C"` works here because he declared the function to take TC using call-by-value. But if an int is passed, it might not work the same on all compilers (32-bit vs. 64-bit issues were or are common in f2c on 64-bit platforms, although I suppose in this case it is a 32-bit platform). It is also always possible to add a C wrapper library to call a standard C function which in turn calls the fortran function.

Comment: I somehow managed to make it work after putting my dll in system32 and exporting the function like this

    `FUNCTION GETPSAT(TC)` 
    `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'_GETPSAT' :: GETPSAT`
    `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: GETPSAT`
 and calling the function `GETPSAT` (not the exported symbol `_GETPSAT`)
 
 but i'm getting always the same wrong results, the dll works fine, i tried calling it from c# and it's giving the right value there

Comment: Do you really use the Visual Fortran?